# Are these two different ways to compute Pearson Correlation as loss function significantly different?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, statistics, deep-learning, pearson-correlation

I am training a Deep Neural Nets using Pearson Correlation as my loss function. To compute the pearson correlation (`p`) between predictions and labels (per batch), I have two methods:

1. Compute `p` row by row and sum them up, and divide them by the batch size to get the avg `p`.
2. Compute `p` in one step: flatten all predictions as `x` and labels as `y`, and compute `p = pearson_loss(x,y)`.

For example, for input:

`X = [[1,2],[3,4]]` and `Y = [[-1,-2],[-3,-4]]`.

1. Compute first row, which is `p1 = pearson_loss([1,2],[-1,-2])`, and then second row, `p2 = pearson_loss([3,4],[-3,-4])`, and get avg `p = (p1+p2)/2.`
2. Compute `p = pearson_loss([1,2,3,4], [-1,-2,-3,-4])`

Does this two method have huge difference?

PS:
In Tensorflow, I defined pearson loss using Keras as followed (use Method 2):

```
def pearson_loss(x, y):
    mx = K.mean(x)
    my = K.mean(y)
    xm, ym = x-mx, y-my
    r_num = K.sum(tf.multiply(xm,ym))
    r_den = K.sqrt(tf.multiply(K.sum(K.square(xm)), K.sum(K.square(ym))))
    r = r_num / r_den
    # ensure r is in range
    r = K.maximum(K.minimum(r, 1.0), -1.0)
    return -r
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did, the resulted pearson correlation is 0.05 (super low). I suspects that it is much harder for method 2 to have high correlation because the number of variable is k times larger than that in method 1, where k is the batch size..